# Jenkins pipeline I need to execute the shell command and the result is the value of def variable. What shall I do? Thank you

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline I need to execute the shell command and the result is the value of def variable.
What shall I do? Thank you

```
def projectFlag = sh("`kubectl get deployment -n ${namespace}| grep ${project} | wc -l`")
    //
    if ( "${projectFlag}" == 1 ) {
         def projectCI = sh("`kubectl get deployment ${project} -n ${namespace} -o jsonpath={..image}`")
         echo "$projectCI"
       } else if ( "$projectCI" == "${imageTag}" ) {
           sh("kubectl delete deploy ${project} -n ${namespaces}")
           def redeployFlag = '1'
            echo "$redeployFlag"
         if ( "$projectCI" != "${imageTag}" ){
          sh("kubectl set image deployment/${project} ${appName}=${imageTag} -n ${namespaces}")
          }
      else {
        def redeployFlag = '2'
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're asking how to save the result of a shell command to a variable for later use?

The way to do this is to use some optional parameters available on the shell step interface. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script for the documentation

```
def projectFlag = sh(returnStdout: true,
    script: "`kubectl get deployment -n ${namespace}| grep ${project} | wc -l`"
    ).trim()
```

Essentially set returnStdout to `true`. The `.trim()` is critical for ensuring you don't pickup a `\n` newline character which will ruin your evaluation logic.